# Fastest way to get a sorted array out of an Iterable of integers

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest strategy to form and sort an array of positive integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063849/fastest-strategy-to-form-and-sort-an-array-of-positive-integers)

What would be the fastest way to get a sorted array from an unsorted iterable of integers ? Currently I do it by iterating over the iterable n no of times (where n is size of list) each time getting the highest from iterable & putting it in array. But I'm looking to clean this up & let some good library do it for me.

Probably I won't mind using any popular libraries like Guava, etc for this purpose.

Comment: Would populating then sorting not be fast enough? Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063849/fastest-strategy-to-form-and-sort-an-array-of-positive-integers?rq=1

Comment: Is `Collections.sort` slow for you?

Comment: Collection.sort uses [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) that is fastest sorting algo on this earth and has been incorporated since JDK 7

Comment: @CAMOBAP: Collections.sort() cannot be used for Iterables, I guess.

Comment: My guess, without timing tests, would be Arrays.sort(Ints.toArray(ImmutableList.copyOf(iterable))).  This will quickly unbox the Integers to ints, where sorting can be more efficient.  IIRC, Comparables are sorted with TimSort, and primatives are sorted with a two-pivot quicksort.

Comment: @AurA TimSort isn't the fastest sorting algorithm on earth, but it's the fastest stable sorting algorithm I know of.  I believe that quicksorts are often faster, but can alter the order of equal values.

Comment: With JDK8 `stream(iterable).sorted(comparator).toArray()`.

Comment: I think the best way for me, right now, is first populate array then sort as suggested by @assylias, so I think I would go that way. Collections.sort() cannot be used with iterables, as per my understanding.

Comment: I know this isn't exactly an answer, but everyone should check out: http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/

Comment: `Ordering.natural().sortedCopy(integers)` does the job just fine.

Comment: I don't think that the marked as duplicate question is essentially the same. @LouisWasserman I believe you should post it as an answer, which should be accepted (sorry for posting after 5 years). I used this to sort the values of a spark pair rdd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, the easiest and probably fastest way is to populate a collection and sort it - I would simply use an ArrayList in this case:

```
List<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Integer i : yourIterable) {
    sortedList.add(i);
}
Collections.sort(sortedList);
```

If you know the size of your Iterable beforehand you can initialise the arraylist with the right size to make an additional efficiency gain:

```
List<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList<>(size);
```

Comment: Thanks for providing it as an answer.. instead of using a list shouldn't I just use the int[] instead, if I know size?

Comment: @user01 Not sure which would be faster. Sorting an array of `int[]` is probably slightly faster than sorting a `List<Integer>`, but creating the array will require unboxing all the integers whereas creating the list will simply copy the references. You should test both approach and decide. If you do, make sure you read [how to write a micro benchmark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java).

Answer (score 7):

It is essentially the same answer as *assylias* has already provided, but if you have Google Guava on the classpath, you can shorten it to :

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

...

List list = Lists.newArrayList(iterable);
Collections.sort(list);
```