# scala.Int in Java variable that stores a value from Scala function

Tags: java, scala

I have a Scala collection `history` as follows:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{Map => mm, Set => mSet}
private var history: mm[Int, mSet[String]] = mm[Int, mSet[String]]()
```

And `getHistory()` Scala function returns `history` to type `mm[Int, mSet[String]]`. This is the Java code that stores the return value of `history`.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map;
import scala.collection.mutable.Set;
??? history = Database.getHistory();
```

The issue is that only `Map<Object, Set<String>>` causes no error. I tried with `Map<Integer, ...>` and `Map<scala.Int, ...>`, but nothing works.

Why is this error? 
I need to get the keys as a set (or iterator) of Integers so that I can iterate over/sort them.

[image]

Comment: Show us the `getHistory` function? (with a return type annotation on it)

Comment: @Chris Martin: It's just one line "history", and the type of history is mm[Int, mSet[String]] where mm is mutable Map, and mSet is mutable Set.

Comment: Without being able to see the context, we can't be sure what the inferred return type is. Showing more code would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the Java "foreach" loop is only coded to handle Java iterable types, and doesn't recognise a Scala Set as something it can iterate over. You can try an old-style for loop calling `iterator`, `next`, etc explicitly yourself, or convert the collection to a Java equivalent first (probably more easily done in the Scala code, though).

Answer (score 1):

This is [a thing](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8293).

Coercing in Scala works fine, as noted:

```
  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
  private var history: mm[Int, mSet[String]] = mm[Int, mSet[String]]()
  history += ((42, mSet("hi")))
  def getMystery(): java.util.Map[Int, mSet[String]] = history.asJava
  def getHistory() = history.asJava.asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[Integer, mSet[String]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`JavaConversion` can convert the keySet() into iterables.

```
    Map<Object, Set<String>> history = Database.getHistory();

    Iterable<Object> keys = JavaConversions.asJavaIterable(history.keySet());

    for (Object key : keys) {
        int k = (int)key;
        System.out.printf("%d-%s\n", k, history.get(k).get().toString());
    }
```

For Int issue, I could change the scala.Int to java.Integer in Scala code, but Object seems to be working fine.

For sorting keys, from the hint from [Fastest way to get a sorted array out of an Iterable of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195787/fastest-way-to-get-a-sorted-array-out-of-an-iterable-of-integers), I can just populate the keys.

```
    List<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object i : keys) {
        sortedList.add((int)i);
    }
    Collections.sort(sortedList);

    for (int key : sortedList) {
        System.out.printf("%d-%s\n", key, history.get(key).get().toString());
    }
```